# Окончания А или И после суффикса ИЩ для сущ. м. рода в форме мн.числа

Tags: грамматика, существительные, окончания

У Розенталя:  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=40#pp40

7. **В разговорной речи** существительные м. рода типа ***домище*** в форме И.п мн.числа наряду с окончанием А имеют окончание И, в результате чего образуются дублетные формы: домища — домищи.

Это позволяет в некоторых случаях дифференцировать формы И.п мн.числа слов м. рода: городищи (большие города) ― городища (древние поселения).

**А вот в современной речи сохраняется это правило?** Если посмотреть парадигму Зализняка, то там ***волчищи, котищи*** (одуш.), ***домища/домищи*** (неод.) и только ***пожарища*** (без дуплета пожарищи ― большие пожары и  пожарища ― места пожара)

ВОЛЧИЩЕ волчи'ще, **волчи'щи,**// волчи'ща, волчи'щ...

КОТИЩЕ коти'ще, **коти'щи,** // коти'ща, коти'щ...

ДОМИЩЕ доми'ще, **доми'ща, доми'щи,**// доми'ща, доми'щ...

ПОЖАРИЩЕ  пожа'рище, **пожа'рища,** //пожа'рища, пожа'рищ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А вот в современной речи сохраняется это правило?

Да, правило Розенталя сохраняется в современной разговорной речи. Более того, оно теперь проникает в литературную норму: многие (большинство?) существительных мужского рода на **-ище** имеют по словарю Лопатина два варианта окончания в форме И.п. множественного числа. Например: *сапожищи — сапожища, кострищи — кострища, огнищи — огнища, кулачищи — кулачища* и т.п.

> Это позволяет в некоторых случаях дифференцировать формы И.п мн.числа
>   слов м. рода: городищи (большие города) ― городища (древние
>   поселения).

Вот это мне показалось очень странным, поскольку **городище** (древнее поселение) имеет средний род. Я проверил у Розенталя, но там всё корректно:

> В разговорной речи существительные мужского рода типа **домище** в
>   форме именительного падежа множественного числа наряду с окончанием
>   **-а** имеют окончание **-и**, в результате чего образуются дублетные формы: **домища — домищи**. Это позволяет в некоторых случаях
>   дифференцировать формы именительного падежа множественного числа слов
>   мужского рода типа домище и слов среднего рода типа **бревнище**...

Поскольку вариативность окончаний вошла в литературную норму, теперь стало возможным отличать подобные пары слов не только в разговорной речи, но и в строгих стилях литературного языка: для множественного числа мужского рода можно систематически использовать окончание **-и**.

Comment: А почему у Зализняка  только котищи и волчищи, а дублет пожарища - пожарищи не обозначен? Вообще говоря, окончание А является основным для сущ. ср. рода, а для сущ. м.р.  - вариантным (окна, столы). Сущ .м.р.,  на ИЩЕ, имея окончание ср.р. Е, по-прежнему относятся к  м.роду. И если не рассматривать дуплеты, то окончание И больше подходит для литературного варианта, чем окончание А (а у Розенталя наоборот). Может быть, мы движемся в истинном направлении, отдавая предпочтение окончанию И.

Comment: @Jasmin С этими словарями якобы Зализняка нужно обращаться очень осторожно. Здесь уже упоминалось раньше, что в сети распространены какие-то "палёные" варианты этого словаря (содержащие явные ошибки и не имеющие отношения к Зализняку). У меня тоже есть какой-то словарь  Зализняка ("Полная акцентуированная парадигма ...") — в нём есть и **пожарища**, и **пожарищи**.

Comment: Но я хотел в ответе привести только какие-то факты, а насчёт "направления движения" я лучше буду ориентироваться на Ваше мнение :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Лично мне окончание И как-то ближе, и притом оно логичнее, ведь и в дуплетах  И относится к м. роду. а А - к среднему роду. А вот частный пример из Нацкорпуса: глазищи (181) - глазища  (67).